# Le « locationized gun » par géorepérage etc. ?

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, anglais, terminologie, suffixes

> A *locationized* gun is one that uses electronic technologies such as
>   [geofencing](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26542714) to restrict its firing to authorized locations [...]
>
> [ Wikipédia, [*Locationized gun*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locationized_gun), je souligne ]

C'est-à-dire empêcher électroniquement l'arme à feu de tirer hormis dans les endroits désignés à cet effet. Le lexique est semble-t-il peu développé en langue anglaise, le mot n'apparaît pas sur *Ngram*, est absent des dictionnaires usuels etc.<sup>1</sup> Quant au suffixe [*-ize*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ize) en anglais et *-iser* ([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-iser), [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/-iser)) en français, il s'agit du changement d'état (*rendre*) vers la sémantique du radical, [*location*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/location/592686) soit l'emplacement, le lieu, le site, la localisation etc., et s'appuyant sur le [*géorepérage*](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=g%C3%A9orep%C3%A9rage&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search). Donc la fonction de l'arme est *limitée* ou *restreinte* ou *astreinte* à un ou des endroits prescrits ; on comprend parfaitement bien le sens et ce dont il s'agit ici.

---

- Existe-t-il un terme ou un élément de vocabulaire technique qui soit
  plus précis qu'une description usuelle avec un adjectif provenant du
  participe passé (comme *limité*), en prenant davantage en compte, par
  exemple, le lexique en TI et dans le domaine des communications, des
  armes à feu, ou qui se base sur le suffixe (*-iser*), qui fasse
  appel à l'Antiquité, ou autrement ?
- Autrement, comment pourrait s'articuler de manière moderne et en
  s'appuyant sur la terminologie des différents domaines le terme
  recherché ici, et peut-on expliquer comment/pourquoi ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> La lecture de *Wikipédia* suggère que ce serait relié aux contraintes au développement commercial vu le cadre légal dans [3 pays sur 200](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_to_keep_and_bear_arms) (Guatemala, Mexico, et les États-Unis) qui protègent le droit au port d'arme à feu dans leur constitution. Il va sans dire que ces contraintes sont inexistantes ailleurs et que ça fait donc l'objet de [développements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Firearms_Directive) [etc](https://www.liberal.ca/realchange/guns/).</sub>

Answer (score 8):

Je ne suis pas certain qu'il existe un terme officiel en français, mais les termes **arme géo-bloquée** (lit. *geoblocked weapon*), **arme géo-limitée** (lit. *geolimited weapon*), ou **arme géo-verrouillée** (lit. *geolocked weapon*) devraient être compris par un francophone.

A titre personnel, j'ai une préférence pour **arme géo-limitée**, car elle oriente plus vers le concept de liste blanche (l'arme fonctionne uniquement dans les zones désignées et nulle part ailleurs), que les autres termes, qui peuvent être interprétés comme des listes noires (l'arme fonctionne partout sauf dans les zone interdites).

Comme en anglais, les néologismes avec "géo" sont assez communs et explicites en français, on comprend immédiatement que *géo-bloqué* signifie *bloqué selon la position géographique*. Le terme géo-bloqué (ou géobloqué) est d'ailleurs utilisé dans le contexte de sites internet rendus inaccessibles selon la position géographique de l'IP du client. Quelques exemples : https://www.google.fr/search?q=g%C3%A9obloqu%C3%A9

Comment: J'éviterais _géoverrouillée_: En général, quand une arme est verrouillée, c'est sur sa cible. Je penche plutôt pour _géobloquée_. Le tout sans tiret.

Comment: Merci ! En effet la question du trait d'union, y avait-il une raison particulière, vu que la lettre suivant géo- n'est [ni i ni u](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4336) ?

Comment: @mouviciel Merci, point intéressant, l'interférence d'autres locutions ou termes, moi j'avais pensé à l’interférence de _usage restreint_ ([par ex.](http://www.ledevoir.com/politique/canada/478109/petition-l-arme-ar-15-demeurera-a-usage-restreint)), essentiellement l'interdiction ou l'autorisation restreinte.

Comment: @mouviciel En passant, n'hésitez pas à rédiger une réponse !  Vous êtes un contributeur expérimenté, et il est moins intéressant de perfectionner une seule _bonne_ réponse, à mon avis, que d'en avoir une multitude. C'est dans la diversité et la nuance qu'on croit trouver une valeur ajoutée. Et donc oui. Merci !

Answer (score 1):

[This proposed edit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3ALocationized_gun) to rename the title of the Wikipedia article that you cite from
 "Locationized gun(s)" to either
 **Location-Aware Guns**;
 **Location-Limited Guns**; or
 **Location-Restricted guns** in English by a certain "Jm3" apparently got nowhere, but the

[**"Location-Aware"**](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/location-aware) part of Jm3's suggestion could lead to
 "**arme géolocalisée**" or perhaps even
 "**arme sensible à l'emplacement**" in French,

just as the "Location-Limited" part of it could lead to Berthim's preferred (and good) answer of "arme géo[-]limitée."

---

Although the "Location-Restricted" part of Jm3's suggestion could certainly lead to constructions using the notions of "restreinte ou astreinte" mentioned in  your question, I seriously doubt if the notion of
"**Localement Restreinte**" offered [here by *Reverso Context*](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/location-restricted) would pass idiomatic (or even grammatical) muster in this (or any) context, as in the doubtful:
"arme [à l'usage] localement restreinte."

Comment: Thanks! Reading the talk & history page for Wikipedia entries is good practice and useful here. It feels maybe _locationized_ is not very apt when compared to those _-aware/limited/restricted_, and I just thought of _-based_, maybe even -barred? It's off topic but when I compare with _weaponize_ or _miniaturize_, it's really _make (into)_ and _restrict to a specific location_ is too much of a stretch i.e. to make into a weapon is not to restrict to the space such a weapon occupies so -ize can't do what -aware does etc. Maybe simply based on _located_ but you end up with sth. like in Fr.

Comment: Yes, l'_arme géolocalisée_ could work with context, but because it's a past participle it could also mean the _result of the firearm having been located_ with positioning technology, which is not the case with your second suggestion based on _sensible_ which is interesting, as from composition with the former you can have _arme geosensible_... which reads beatifully although I'm not certain it immediately conveys what this is about but nevertheless. Thanks!